# Flutter: oauth2_client won't grab access token from API

Tags: android, ios, flutter, oauth-2.0, android-manifest

I'm currently trying to develop a personal project using Flutter, which uses the AniList APIv2 [Anilist API GitBooks](https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/).

For this project, I'm currently using the oauth2_flutter package to create an oauth2 client (some keywords and clientID have been crossed out):

```dart
class AnilistOAuthClient extends OAuth2Client {
  AnilistOAuthClient({
    required String redirectUri,
    required String customUriScheme,
  }) : super(
          authorizeUrl: 'https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/authorize',
          tokenUrl: 'https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/token',
          redirectUri: redirectUri,
          customUriScheme: customUriScheme,
        );
}

OAuth2Helper createAnilistOAuthHelper() {
  AnilistOAuthClient anilistOAuthClient = AnilistOAuthClient(
    customUriScheme: "com.XXXX.app", 
    redirectUri: "com.XXXX.app://login-redirect",
  );

  return OAuth2Helper(
    anilistOAuthClient,
    grantType: OAuth2Helper.implicitGrant,
    clientId: 'XXXX',
  );
}
```

I then call `createAnilistOAuthHelper()` in a cubit event to fetch a token from the API:

```dart
  void anilistLoginPressed() async {
    OAuth2Helper helper = AnilistClient().helper;
    try{
      await helper.getToken();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      emit(AnilistLoginErrorState());
      return;
    }

    helper.getToken().then((token) {
      final tokenBox = Hive.box('userToken');
      tokenBox.put("token", token!.accessToken);
      print("Token: ${tokenBox.get("token")}");
    });

    emit(AnilistLoginPressedState());
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when the `fetchToken()` function is called and the WebView tab opens, once a user signs in it gives me the following error:

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","message":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.","hint":"Check that all required parameters have been provided"}
```

I've been told that this error stems from the fact that my redirectURi is invalid, but it is exactly the same as the redirect URL in the API client dashboard: [image]

The thing is, when I set `redirectUri` to a blank string `""`, it proceeds to work flawlessly on iOS, but on Android, it fails to retreive the key but properly redirects itself to the app.
Here is my manifest.xml for Android:

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="com.xxxx.app" android:host="login-redirect"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

I've been stumped on this for the longest time, can anyone help me?